# how to store manifests in resources using GCC?

Tags: winapi, gcc

The documentation states ([Enabling Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx)):

> 1. Link to ComCtl32.lib and call InitCommonControls.
> 2. Add a file called YourApp.exe.manifest to your source tree that has the XML manifest format.
> 3. Add the manifest to your application's resource file as follows:

```
       CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "YourApp.exe.manifest"
```

How to achieve this using the GCC toolchain (or generically)? Is it possible to compile this using C rather than C++?

> 

(update)

> ```
> windres --input test.rc --output test.res --output-format=coff
> gcc -o test.exe test.c test.res -lmsvcr90
> ```

compiles correctly but I'm having some problems with the VC2008 runtime dependency, I cannot restart my PC right now so I'll ruminate on my findings later

Comment: A basic example is [available here](http://cournape.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/how-to-embed-a-manifest-into-a-dll-with-mingw-tools-only/).

Comment: The Win32 API is designed primarily as a C-based API, so yes, this can be accomplished using either C or C++.